# Is there a direct way to upgrade from Cordova 1.9.0 to 2.9.0?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am facing splash screen problem for iPhone 5. Splash screen looks proper first time then suddenly it displays a smaller splash image which was a bug in cordova library. So, i want to upgrade my Cordova version.Can i directly switch to 2.9.0 from 1.9.0 because i am unable to download 2.0.0 version ? I am getting network error after 90% download while network is working properly.

Comment: Follow this link you may get answer http://scottdizzle.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=849

Comment: Since you start over, you might as as well go for 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think no. But you can make new app based on Phonegap 2.9, install your plugins again and simple copy browser part from old version of your application to current.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can directly upgrade from 1.9 to 2.9 - that's a big jump. You should try it and let us know how it works. If it is too much work to make a fresh 2.9 app and copy your code over, you could follow the upgrade guide for iOS. If you apply the steps in order, it should work. The guide is here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS

Comment: I am creating a new project with latest version of Phonegap. As i don't have much knowledge of Phonegap can you please let me know which files i will have to modify to make it work ?